# Как сделать в BottomNavigationView связи?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как организовать в BottomNavigationView связи ? чтобы когда я нажимал кнопку назад он возвращался на одну вкладку назад а не выходил из приложения.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity () {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_dashboard,
            R.id.navigation_notifications,
            R.id.navigation_fourth,
            R.id.navigation_fifth))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: так он и должен так делать. скорее всего, вы, когда переходите на новый фрагмент, закрываете старый. приложите код навигации в другой фрагмент.

Comment: appBarConfiguration - это список ваших фрагментов, которые считаются "корневыми". оставьте в этом листе только главный / основной фрагмент.

Comment: Если я правильно понял - у вас навигация через BottomNavigationView. Она, по задумаке корпорации зла должна работать именно так - никакой обратной навигации. Если она нужна, то стандартного решения нет. Надо вручную разруливать. Т.е. написать свой стэк навигации и им манипулировать.

Comment: Вот тут описано: "When a bottom navigation icon is tapped, the user is taken to the top-level navigation destination associated with that icon." Т.е. пользователь всегда на верхнем уровне, назад некуда идти.
https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage